# React Datepicker include days in the future without weekends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using React Datepicker found here: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-11

What I'm trying to do is only allow the user to select a day UP TO 3 "business" days in advance. Using `filterDate` I was able to filter calendar to only display weekdays. I see in the documentation they have a `includeDates` prop to allow user to only select certain dates. I'm trying to figure out how to only include up to 3 business days. So if today is Friday. The user will only be able to select: Friday, Monday, Tuesday for that week.

Here is my code:

```
        this.state = {
            dateFrom: new Date(),
        }

render() {

    const isWeekday = date => {
        const day = getDay(date);
        return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
    };      


    return (
        <div>
        
            <DatePicker
                selected={this.state.dateFrom}
                filterDate={isWeekday}
                //includeDates={[new Date(), addDays(new Date(), 1)]}
                onChange={date=>this.setState({dateFrom: date })}
                className="form-control"
            />


        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Break it down by writing it out in words:  if today is Monday, I want today, today+1, today+2. If today is Tuesday, I want ...

Comment: where is getDay defined?